# How do I get a specific child in firebase realtime databse in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering how I can get a specific child of a firebase realtime database path.
Example:

```
users/
  User1: John,
  User2: Jeff,
  User3: Jerry
```

Whenever I try this below, I just get undefined in the console.

```
get(child(dbRef, "users/"))
    .then((snapshot) =>{
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        let user = child.val().User1;
        console.log(user)
      })
    })
```

This ends up console.logging undefined. How would I just console.log User1?

---

I am working on a login system for a website but when I try to get the values from the realtime database, I get undefined four times in the console. Here is what it looks like in the database.

```
Hehefunnyboi2/
      FirstName: Hehe,
      LastName: Funny,
      Email: Hehefunnyboi2@gmail.com,
      Password: 2oibynnufeheH
```

And here is the code,

```
get(child(dbRef, inputted-username.value))
    .then((snapshot) =>{
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        let email = child.val().Email;
        console.log(name)
      })
    })
```

So I want to have the user input a username, then it will find if that username has data stored to it in the database (in this case imagining that the user inputted "Hehefunnyboi2" to the system). When I just want to console.log the under the assigned username, I just get four "undefined" in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *read* all users, but only log `User1`, that'd be:

```
get(child(dbRef, "users/"))
    .then((snapshot) =>{
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        if (child.key === 'User1') {
          let user = child.val();
          console.log(user)
        }
      })
    })
```

Or:

```
get(child(dbRef, "users/"))
    .then((snapshot) =>{
      let user = child.val().User1;
      console.log(user)
    })
```

To only get `User1` would be:

```
get(child(dbRef, "users/User1"))
    .then((snapshot) =>{
      let user = snapshot.val();
      console.log(user)
    })
```

Comment: I mean without specififying the path even more. The idea is to assign User1 to a variable.

Comment: I don't understand. In order to only get `User1` you would need to specify `User1` somewhere. If not in the path, then where *do* you want to specifyt hat?

Comment: How would I find the specific User1 path using a variable? For example, imagine I have a login system. I want to have the user enter in the username, then (for testing reasons) I would want the email under the associated username to be console logged.

Comment: This is all probably very clear in your mind, but I'm struggling to understand. If the two additional examples I added to my answer don't help, please edit your question to show in code what you **know** about the user and what you want to show based on that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I tried your second method and all I got was undefined in the console.

Comment: I updated the code sample

Comment: I wrote up a minimal repro here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-v9-rtdb-query?file=index.js

Comment: Any update here @Hehefunnyboi2?